# Why does `match` give the memory reference instead of the actual match data `"foo"`?

Tags: ruby, regex

I got expected result with `=~` but not with `match`. Why does `match` give the memory reference instead of the actual match data `"foo"`? And why do the references change in every run of the same statement?

```
s= "foo"
/(?=foo)foo/ =~ s    # => 0
/(?=foo)foo/.match s # => #<MatchData:0x2e6a490>
/(?=foo)foo/.match s # => #<MatchData:0x2e66390>
/(?=foo)foo/.match s # => #<MatchData:0x2e64310>
```

Comment: Please ask only one or two questions, not four. Stack Overflow wants the question on a page to be focused and concise. Multiple questions cause the answers to wander and be difficult to follow.

Comment: @theTinMan Are you suggesting me for different post with the second part?

Comment: A different post, or spend time reading the documentation, and books, as these differences are just implementation details

Comment: I'm suggesting you figure out what is the essential part of the question. As is, it's overly broad and your questions don't show that you've taken the time to really read the documentation. All of those questions are answered in books on Ruby and are summarized around the internet. [Pseudo Variables and Pre-defined Variables](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Variables_and_Constants#Pseudo_Variables) is an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@theTinMan is mostly correct, the reference is the output of the object's `to_s` or `inspect` method (IRB just calls it, and `Object`'s implementation is used via inheritance if it has not been over-riden)

The `=~` method returns the match position, because that is how it is defined. A `MatchData` object is actually a richer object that has information on the match, such as the offset (the position), any captures, etc. In essence, you can use the returned `MatchData` to access the values that the `$~`, `$1`, `$2`, etc. variables normally hold, with a clearer interface.

Docs for `MatchData`: http://apidock.com/ruby/MatchData

Comment: See my **EDIT**, I just updated the description with few queries ?

Answer (score 1):

That's not a memory reference per se, it's the object ID, and it's how IRB displays objects that don't define an `inspect` or `to_s` method. The base [`Object.to_s`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-to_s) method's output is what you're seeing.

The object being displayed is the result of `match` and gets recreated each time you use the method.

Comment: Ah, I thought, he was asking why `#match` doesn't return match position (as `=~` does).

Comment: See my **EDIT**, I just updated the description with few queries ?